Setting up latex font
does anyone know what is the name of the font for the first equation with the straight integral sign and brackets?
and how to set that font in latex?

The first equation was created on an old, pre-2007 version of Microsoft Word, with the Times New Roman font, that was shipped with Word. Source: https://chalkdustmagazine.com/blog/is-there-a-perfect-maths-font/.
They can be used in LaTeX if you have the fonts for yourself, but I am sure they won't have proper math support. The equations would look poor as in the first example.
However, I recommend the following alternatives compatible with Times New Roman, which shall give better results.

XITS.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math, microtype}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8]{XITS Math Regular}

\begin{document}
    \[f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\symup{\pi} \symrm{i}} \oint_\gamma \left(\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - a)^{n+1}}\right)\symrm{d}\zeta\]
\end{document}



TeX Gyre Termes

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math, microtype}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\everydisplay{\Umathoperatorsize\displaystyle=5ex}

\begin{document}
    \[f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\symup{\pi} \symrm{i}} \oint_\gamma \left(\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - a)^{n+1}}\right)\symrm{d}\zeta\]
\end{document}



STIX Two

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math, microtype}
\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont[StylisticSet=8]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
    \[f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\symup{\pi} \symrm{i}} \oint_\gamma \left(\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - a)^{n+1}}\right)\symrm{d}\zeta\]
\end{document}



New TX. The above fonts require LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile. New TX can be compiled on pdfLaTeX.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[upint]{newtx}

\begin{document}
    \[f^{(n)}(a) = \frac{n!}{2\uppi \mathrm{i}} \oint_\gamma \left(\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - a)^{n+1}}\right)\mathrm{d}\zeta\]
\end{document}



Great answer, is nice to be able to compare.
